# How can I make the contents of my Xcode project visible to a Swift playground

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

Is there a way I can import the contents of an Xcode project into a playground without copying and pasting classes.

I know that Files in the project are not visible, but is there someway to use an Umbrella header or something to import them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the apple WWDC video on the playground, I believe the answer is no. Playgrounds are completely separate from Xcode projects.

Comment: Ok thanks, that sucks though